# DynamoDB with SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, aws-iot

Is there a way that I publish a message to AWS IOT Device shadow and save it to dynamo db and dynamo db will put this data to SQS so that I have a worker thread running on my local server will fetch the data.

Comment: You can chain this type of actions with Lambda: When a new item appears in DynamoDB luanch a lambda that send it to the SQS of your choice.

Comment: Thanks @Conti I am able to send data to the sqs server.Is there any when that i can retrieve this in my local server in realtime using celery.

Comment: Since I have not worked with Celery, I'll give you my thought: Using another lambda, you can detect when a message arrives the specified SQS, so you may send it to an "endpoint" of your choice, something that Celery could read. I'm thinking about developing a small middleware that connect both sides. Another option is to use AWS SDK in the Celery side to retrieve directly from SQS.